# Foundation Top-bar Navigation styles

Tags: css, navigation, sass, zurb-foundation

How can I override the default styles of the top-bar, nav-bar, etc ?

PS: I read the Foundation Docs, about the Top Bar and i have 2 use SASS, but I don't have a clue how do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SASS version comes with a settings file (`_settings.scss` or `_settings.sass`) where you can configure the colors and breakpoints for the whole Foundation library.

The top bar elements are at the bottom of the file. Just uncomment and alter the line with the variable you want to change.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with using SASS or SCSS as the site suggests. Do I need to learn this syntax in order to restyle the topbar? I love its functionality but it seems like the difficulty in redesigning it is much more difficult than I would expect.

Comment: You would. `_settings.scss` just defines variables that are used in the rest of Foundation, and CSS doesn't have variables. SCSS is pretty close to plain CSS, though, so it shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 1):

I created an .app style sheet and attached it as an external style sheet. Within the style sheet, I created,

```
.top-bar {

background: whatever color;

}

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button)
{
background: whatever color;
}
```

I am still learning Foundation and how to manipulate elements.  I would using the inspection tool in Google Chrome to determine the elements to add to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your custom css file::

```
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
    background:black;
    color: white;
    }

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
    background:red;
    color: white;
    }
```